# Splitting string at parentheses in Java

Tags: java, regex

Now,if I have a String like this:

```
String start = "(1374)(48.4%)(32)(100%)(290)(43.1%)";
```

How can I extract the six numbers `1374 48.4 32 100 290 43.1` or `1374 48.4% 32 100% 290 43.1%`?  Can it be done with a regex?

Comment: by splitting the `String`.

Comment: Without regex `start.split(")")`

Comment: Match `\d+(?:\.\d+)` or anything that is wrapped in parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for a regex identifying floating point numbers: `([+-]?(\d+\.)?\d+)`

```
String start = "(1374)(48.4%)(32)(100%)(290)(43.1%)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([+-]?(\\d+\\.)?\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(start);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Or use a regex that also makes sure that the brackets are there:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([+-]?(\\d+\\.)?\\d+)\\%?\\)");
```

Comment: Not going to match `48.4%`

Comment: Note that this *will* match .4 with no leading number, which I think is wrong.

Comment: @Chill: That's normally considered a valid floating point number.

Comment: @Chill: Changed it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it without a regex!

```
int i = 0;
while (i < start.length()) {
  while (i < start.length()) {
    char ch = start.charAt(i);
    // Maybe add other characters, e.g. %, if desired.
    if (Character.isDigit(ch) || ch == '.') {  
      break;
    }
    ++i;
  }
  int startOfBlock = i;
  while (i < start.length()) {
    char ch = start.charAt(i);
    if (!Character.isDigit(ch) && ch != '.') {
      break;
    }
    ++i;
  }
  if (i > startOfBlock) {
    System.out.println(start.substring(startOfBlock, i));
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's not. It's a problem suited for regex and the poster asked for a regex solution.

Comment: ["If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail). Just giving an alternative approach :)

Comment: Heh -- I realized that came off as snarky. I didn't mean any hostility, I just wanted to point out that this is probably not an ideal answer even though it's an acceptable way to approach the problem.

Comment: @Chill no worries.

Answer (score 0):

or u can try the following regex `[\d\.%]+` it gives u the combinations of the strings containing the following items
 `\d` (digit) 
`\.` dot and 
`%` procentage sign 
 one or more times
 click here for a [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS6hQ4/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String start = "(1374)(48.4%)(32)(100%)(290)(43.1%)";
    for(String splitString : start.split("[()]")) {
        System.out.print(splitString + " ");
    }
```